# Typed Array should be recycled after use with #recycle()

Tags: java, android, class, recycle

My code is showing this warning message:

> Typed Array should be recycled after use with #recycle() for **obtainedTypedArray**

Code:

```
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewgroup)
{
    ImageView imageview;
    if (view == null)
    {
        imageview = new ImageView(b);
        imageview.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams(110, 110));
        imageview.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
        imageview.setAdjustViewBounds(false);
        imageview.setScaleType(android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    } else
    {
        imageview = (ImageView)view;
    }
    imageview.setImageResource(a.getResources().obtainTypedArray(0x7f050000).getResourceId(i, -1)); //*warning*Typed Array should be recycled after use with #recycle()
    return imageview;
}
```

Comment: So, I think you better make a typed array, set it with obtainTypedArray and then dismiss it properly with ta.recyle(); as soon as you don't need it anymore (that is, before the return statement).

Comment: buddy its showing an error `The method recyle() is undefined for the type MainActivity`

Comment: Yes. In facts you should recycle your typed array, not the activity. In my comment I said **ta.recycle();**, not **this.recycle();**. It wasn't a typo. "ta" standing for "typed array", the one you should have created before using imageview.setImageResource....

Comment: so you telling me to put `imageview.recycle();` before the end of return statement ?

Comment: no, no, no. **ta.recycle();** Imagine you set **TypedArray ta = ...** then you use it, then you recycle it.

Comment: this means i have to put the Typed Array dot recycle 
that means `obtainTypedArray.recycle();` ?

Comment: Please, have a look at the refence [site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use a `recycle();` at the end of your `obtainTypedArray()` statement.
do not use `hex` values, may lead to complications in your code in future.

Answer (score 18):

You should hold onto the `TypedArray` you get back from `obtainTypedArray()` and call `recycle()` on it after using it.

Also, hard-coding a hex value like `0x7f050000` is unlikely to be the right answer.

Comment: @MojoJojo You don't (shouldn't) hard-code it.  Use the name instead, such as `R.id.foo`.