# Is "TypedArray should be recycled" a false positive in Lint when using try-with-resources?

Tags: android, try-with-resources, autocloseable

I have read the [dozens](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21354501/1955202) of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7252839/1955202) here on SO regarding recycling `TypedArray`s, but I guess they are a bit too old and written before we could widely use `try-with-resource` statements, so none of them talk about using the `AutoCloseable` implementation of the `TypedArray`, which is present since [API Level 31](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray#close())

So the question remains: **is this a false positive in Lint?**
[image: screenshot of Lint warning]

If anything, that warning should be a minSDK warning if applicable, right?
Can we simply write the following since the full try-with support (if we do it after SDK Level >= 31 check)?

```
try (TypedArray array = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs) {
  // Do someting
}
// End of method
```

My guess is yes, as this is the `AutoCloseable` implementation of `TypedArray`
[image: screenshot of docs]

Answer (score -1):

> So the question remains: is this a false positive in Lint?

No, it is not. Because `close` method in `AutoCloseable` interface is not magically called when using try/catch.

Instead you have to use `use` method and then and only then you can get rid of try/catch like following:

```
getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs).use({
  // Do something
});
```

But, be aware that `use` method from `TypedArray` class is available only [since Android 31](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray#close())

If you prefer a backwards compatible solution, you can use `use` method from `androidx.core:core-ktx` library.

As `TypedArray` also provides of a `use` method you will have to take care of adding the following import:

```
import androidx.core.content.res.use
```

Comment: Sorry I cannot find a `use` method in the documentation (the one you linked or any other) and neither can I get your code example to compile or find `use` in the source code. Can you double-check your answer please and make sure we're talking about the same thing, i.e. not `recycle`?